# Editing /etc/fstab to add quota restriction

Tags: centos

So i've been trying to edit the /etc/fstab file to add the "usrquota" however I tried editing it and it fails any commands that I should follow on this guide afterwards([Quotas in vsftpd?](https://serverfault.com/questions/37737/quotas-in-vsftpd)), this system is a VPS with just one drive running CentOS

Current contents(the original)

```
  none    /dev/pts        devpts  rw      0       0
```

Mount output

```
[root@s1 etc]# mount
/dev/simfs on / type reiserfs (rw,usrquota,grpquota)
proc on /proc type proc (rw)
sysfs on /sys type sysfs (rw)
none on /dev type tmpfs (rw)
none on /dev/pts type devpts (rw)
none on /proc/sys/fs/binfmt_misc type binfmt_misc (rw)
```

Mtab contents

```
/dev/simfs / reiserfs rw,usrquota,grpquota 0 0
proc /proc proc rw 0 0
sysfs /sys sysfs rw 0 0
none /dev tmpfs rw 0 0
none /dev/pts devpts rw 0 0
none /proc/sys/fs/binfmt_misc binfmt_misc rw 0 0
```

First bit it fails upon after editing the fstab

```
[root@s1 ~]# quotacheck -cug /home
quotacheck: Mountpoint (or device) /home not found.
quotacheck: Can't find filesystem to check or filesystem not mounted with quota option.
```

Would appreciate any help

Comment: what does `mount` return? What's in `/etc/mtab` ?

Comment: Updated :) Could you take a look?

Comment: Looks good actually. How do commands fail? Is it `quotacheck` that fails after creating `/aquota.user` and `/aquota.group` saying that there is no support for quotas?

Comment: Im guessing thats because I haven'tassigned user quatalimitation to that? or?

Comment: did you try adding a line for /dev/simfs as in an answer below to your fstab? quotacheck might be looking in the wrong place too.

Comment: Why are you trying to mount a volume `fstab` doesn't describe?

Comment: Um Itried adding a couple different ones, at that point /home was defined, whatshould I add exactly? As it's getting rather confusing

Comment: Since you do not have a device for /home you may only set up quotas for the whole root file system (which is perfectly ok).

Answer (score 1):

VPS environment does not update your `fstab` so automated tools such as `webmin` can just be configured to look at `/etc/mtab` instead. Another option would probably be to 
add the following line to `/etc/fstab`

```
    /dev/simfs / reiserfs rw,usrquota,grpquota 0 0
```

Then you may follow the advice that you referred to replacing `/home` with `/`

Comment: This might be the key why you are unable to get this working as described in the CentOS guide.  You haven't specified where your machine is hosted and what type of management access you have.  I (and the author of the CentOS documentation) assumed you were working on a regular CentOS server but if the system has been configured to use webmin you will ahve to check either the documentation of the hosting company or a plain webmin guide.  But as @dmitri-chubarov wrote you need to place quotas on a file system as a whole, if /home isn't a separate file system you can't limit just that directory.

Answer (score 0):

What file system do you want to place quotas on?  The example you give is a pseudo filesystem.  I doubt you can place quotas on that and it certainly would not do anything useful.

[Chapter 7. Implementing Disk Quotas](http://www.centos.org/docs/5/html/Deployment_Guide-en-US/ch-disk-quotas.html) of the CentOS deployment guide describes in detail what is needed.

Comment: I've had a read of thataswell and got stuck on the exact same part when it came to editing fstab